# Is it possible to see the coordinate plane as a background when using opengl

Tags: opengl, background, coordinate

I know I can set the background to different colors, but i was wonder if it was possible to show the coordinate system easily instead. Or if i'm going to have to create each axis myself. I am aware opengl plots vertices on the system I just want to see it. I am using free glut and opengl.

Comment: "Or if i'm going to have to create each axis myself."  Yup.

Comment: Thats because you see your "backgroud" in a wrong way. There is no background just clearing your screen with a color.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand more about opengl and how it operates. I can create my own axis myself through projection matrixes and other various techniques.